# ERROR: raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.") django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django, pandas, sqlite

I am kinda new to Python Django and have already done researches on the error that I am getting but cannot find answers that will solve the problem. I have tried modifying my codes to the answers given in other similar post in stackoverflow as this and in other websites and forums but found no solutions. So here is my story!

I am currently working on an ordinary Django project with only one app inside the project directory. Everything works fine until I decided to connect to my project's default sqlite3 db file named 'db.sqlite3' so as I put these lines of codes in my views.py (which I need connect to the default sqlite3 db file so that I could perform data cleaning from there and export it as a new sqlite3 db file with cleaned data).

```
**views.py**

import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

def Dashboard():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
    df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from Client', connection)
    connection.close()
    print (df)
```

Once I run my views in PyCharm, I got this error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

So I did some researches and found out that I need to define the ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, there are a lot of different methods to define the ENV found on the net but I decided to use this since it worked.

(In PyCharm, click Run > Edit Configurations... > Environment variables > Type "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" (left column) "heath.settings" (right column) > Click OK > Apply > OK ) 
*health is the name of my project*

When I run the views again, the error mentioned above disappeared (assuming that it was fixed already) but was replaced with another error statement.

> raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.") 
>        django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

I checked my INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py and I don't think there is anything wrong with it.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'records.apps.RecordsConfig',
]
```

I also tried placing these two lines of codes on top of settings.py initially and later in other lines/portions of settings.py but failed to debug the error.

```
import django
django.setup()
```

Would anyone help me with the error I am getting? Thank you!

Comment: Not sure about the error, but I'm curious why you are trying to manually connect and make a simple raw query, rather than using Django's built-in database abstraction functionality.

Comment: Hi there Robin, I decided to use this method because from the online tutorials on data analytics that I have been watching, this is the method that they have been using to connect to the default sqlite db file, import, and perform data cleaning on those data. Perhaps if there is another way to generate the same output without getting any errors and error like this, could you suggest? Thanks

Comment: Well I can't give a complete introduction to Django's database layer in a comment here, but try this page from the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial02/

Comment: Also I've just noticed where you said you got the error when "running your views in Pycharm". I'm not 100% sure what you mean here, but it's important to say that Django is a web application framework. It's designed to run on a web server (Django comes with its own development server), and Django views run in that context, accepting an HTTP request and producing a response. It doesn't make much sense to run views as standalone functions. So if you're building a website, run the server and view the results in the browser - that should eliminate the errors. If not, you shouldn't be using Django.

Comment: I got what you mean by "building a website, run the server and view the results in the browser - ..." but that is not the case, in fact that works perfectly fine. The one I am pertaining to is when you open PyCharm (with your project opened), you will see the Run tab on top, I clicked Run > Run 'views', when I did that, the "Run console", I am not sure what it is properly called, displays with the error mentioned ^. I am not sure if I am doing it right

Comment: but what I am trying to achieve is something similar to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gC-0CaRzR48 integrated to my django project. I wanna see the 'Client' table once I run the def Dashboard() view function ^. Am I doing it right Robin? thanks!

Comment: But the view functions should never be called directly in your own code. You attach them to URLs, and they tell the server what to do when a request is made to that URL. (And if that involves displaying something to the user then you use an html template.) I believe the error you are asking about here is happening because you are trying to run some parts of Django individually.

Comment: Exactly, is it not possible to run some part of Django individually to test if (like in my case) the table 'Client' from db.sqlite3 will be printed on the "console"?

Comment: It may be possible to run some parts, although as this isn't something I've ever done - so I couldn't really advise on this. But the more relevant question is what are you trying to achieve with this code? There is nothing in that snippet in your question that requires Django - so forget Django and run it as a standalone script.